# Npm download tarball failed due to broken url

Tags: node.js, npm, openstreetmap

I'm trying to install tileserver-gl to host my own OSM server on my windows machine.

At the moment, I have tried to install locally and via npm without much success. 
The issue being, npm is unable to get 'mapbox-gl-native' from the specific web address.

[image: Unable To Get URL]

I have seen similar issues to this, from this github issue thread , [Link Here.](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/4971) In which they have provided an alternate download link.

I have tried to download the tileserver-gl files from the repo, manually put the required files inside, run npm install & npm install from source but to no avail.

There are online topics which said to use Node v4 , which i already tried on both Node v6 and Node v4 .

How do I fix this issue?